# NER tagging schema for non-contiguous tokens

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, named-entity-recognition

The most common tagging procedure for NER is IOB. But it seems that this kind of tagging is limited to cases where tokens from the same entity are contiguous.

So for instance,

`Jane Smith is walking in the park` would be tagged as: `B-PER I-PER O O O O O`

And here my PER entity is the concatenation of `[Jane, Smith]`

If we tweak the example:

`Jane and James Smith are walking in the park`

`B-PER O B-PER I-PER O O O O O`

Now the issue is that the entities we would get are `[Jane]` and `[James, Smith]` because the IOB tagging does not allow to link Jane to Smith.

Is there any tagging schema that would allow to mark as entities both `[Jane, Smith]` and `[James, Smith]`?

Comment: [Nested Named Entity Recognition](https://paperswithcode.com/task/nested-named-entity-recognition)

Comment: I looked at the GENIA corpus, but it doesn't seem to be the same problem. In Genia, a nested entity looks like it's an entity is contained into another entity (but not the same type of entity). In my problem, there are essentially 2 separate entities of the same type that overlap on a token, but they are not nested per se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, about doing this without a new data format:

There are a paper and repo about doing this using [TextAE](http://textae.pubannotation.org/) for this:

[paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7362949/#:%7E:text=However%2C%20some%20entities%20are%20represented,%2Dcontiguous%2C%20or%20discontiguous%20entities.)

[repo](https://github.com/jakelever/textae)

However, looking at their examples and yours, it seems like you could improve on [what they did](https://github.com/jakelever/textae/blob/stable/4/analysis/findNonContigious.py#L14-L17) by using dependency parsing. If you look at [the dependency parse](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=Jane%20and%20James%20Smith%20are%20walking%20in%20the%20park&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=0&cph=0) of "Jane and James Smith are walking in the park", you can see that spaCy understands that Jane is conjoined with Smith. So after running entity extraction, you could do a dependency parse step, then edit your entities based on that.

**Now, to answer the real question.** I have seen multi-dimensional labels that work in the following way (assume you have a maximum of ten entities per sentence:

```py
empty = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

tokens = ["Jane", "and", "James", "Smith", "are", "walking", "in", "the", "park"]
labels = [
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
labels = labels + [empty] * (10-len(labels))
```

If you have more than one entity type, you can use those instead of just `1`.

This format works better with BERT anyway, since the BIO format is a pain when you have to split up tokens into BPE anyway.

Comment: Looks like your solution is actually reframing the NER task into a relation extraction task (because essentially, this N*N matrix is a relation matrix, and you're trying to predict which token is related to which other tokens). Am I correct?
And in that case, it would make more sense actually doing NER with the usual BIO format, and then do the relation extraction (kinda like a joint NER/RE task).

Comment: I don't agree. this will show relations only in as much as they share a token. this is framing NER as a token classification task. doing one row per entity is just a way to allow overlap

Comment: Do you have some source discussing this method? I don't really see it as token classification anymore, as your target is a N*N matrix with N being the number of tokens (very much like RE) but I agree it would work in my scenario

Comment: I will keep an eye out. I have seen this technique before of lifting something up into a higher dimensional space, but I can't think of an example offhand. I don't know if I have seen it for token tagging before. it's a sparser output space, so I imagine there will be some hiccups...